# How to pass multiple arguments to function in map()

Tags: python-3.x, lambda

`A="HACK" k=2 for x in range(int(k)): D=list(combinations(a,x+1)) E=list(map(lambda y:print(*y,sep=''),D))`
This prints
A
C
H
K
AC
AH
AK
CH
CK
HK

How do I print the above output without using for loop using lambda and map()?
I've tried :- list(map(combinations,(A,k))
But show error . . .

Answer (score 1):

First, you can write the body of the for loop using a single expression:

```
list(map(lambda y : print(*y, sep=''), combinations(A, x+1)))
```

Then, to avoid the for loop you can wrap the body into another call to map on range(k):

```
list(map(lambda x : 
    list(map(lambda y : print(*y, sep=''), combinations(A, x+1))),
    range(k)
))
```